# Angular response.status not running

Tags: angularjs, http

From what I've researched, it looks like the $http interceptor is deprecated, so I'm not sure what the current best practice for this is. I'm returning a 409 status if a user attempts to register with a username that is already taken, and I'm attempting to handle it client-side with the following:

```
$http.post('/register-user',payloadCredentials,config).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 409) {
                $scope.errorResponseUserName = "Username already exists.";
                $scope.error = true;
                clearPasswords();
                clearUsername();
            } else {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $location.path("/")
            }
        });
```

I'm still new to Angular, so I'm not sure why this function seemingly doesn't run if a status code interrupts it. The other questions on SO I've seen apply to the past Angular style of using the `.success()` and `.error()` callbacks, but I haven't found any situations using the newer `.then()` syntax. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for all promises, then() expects two callbacks; one called when the promise is resolved (i.e. in case of success), one when it's rejected (i.e. in case of error). A 409 status is an error. So you (most probably) need

```
$http.post('/register-user',payloadCredentials,config).then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    $location.path("/")
}, function(response) {
    $scope.errorResponseUserName = "Username already exists.";
    $scope.error = true;
    clearPasswords();
    clearUsername();
});
```

Or you could also use catch():

```
$http.post('/register-user',payloadCredentials,config).then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    $location.path("/")
}).catch(function(response) {
    $scope.errorResponseUserName = "Username already exists.";
    $scope.error = true;
    clearPasswords();
    clearUsername();
});
```

I'm not sure where you get that interceptors were deprecated. There is no deprecation mention in [their documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). But anyway, interceptors don't look like the appropriate tool for handling this specific situation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I was looking at, but it's good to know it was incorrect. It's been confusing learning the framework because I feel like most of the questions I see people ask are before the `.then()` syntax was introduced. But after seeing your answer the difference between the two makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Angular DID deprecate the `.success()`/ `.error()` callbacks for `$http`, but not interceptors.